# Compound distributions when $N$ and $\xi_{i}$ are correlated

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

I know the following theorem:
Let me define $\eta=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}$, where $\left(\xi_{i}\right)_{i}$ variables are $iid$ and they are independent from the non-negative integer random variable $N$, then

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\eta\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(N\right)\cdot\mathbb{E}\left(\xi_{i}\right)$$

and
$$\mathbb{D}^{2}\left(\eta\right)=\mathbb{D}^{2}\left(\xi_{i}\right)\mathbb{E}\left(N\right)+\mathbb{E}^{2}\left(\xi_{i}\right)\mathbb{D}^{2}\left(N\right).$$

What happens if $N$ and each $\xi_{i}$ are corraleted?

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\eta\right) =\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(\eta\mid N=n\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}\mid N=n\right)\mathbf{P}\left(N=n\right)$$

In case when $N$ and $\xi_{i}$ are independent, then

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}\mid N=n\right)=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}\cdot\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}\cdot\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}\right)\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}\right),
$$

but if $N$ and $\xi_{i}$ are not independent, then

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}\mid N=n\right)=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_{i}\cdot\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_{i}\cdot\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\chi_{\left(N=n\right)}\right)}=?
$$

Comment: If $\xi_i$ and $N$ are correlated, then you need to know something about the dependence otherwise you cannot compute anything.

Comment: Usually the dependency is given by a markov kernel / rcd $\mu(B,\omega)$, in which case $$E(f(\xi,N)) = \iint f(x,n) \mu(dx,n) \nu(dn) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int f(x,n)\mu(dx,n)P(N=n)$$